# Test folder does not exist, using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have generated the project using

```
rails new app -T
```

**Shouldn't this command make a test folder by default?**

I am trying to add the `test` folder in my ruby project. here is my `gem` file:

```
group :development, :test do

  gem 'rspec', '~> 3.4'
  gem 'byebug'

  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

and then :

```
bundle install --without production
```

it does not generate the test folder inside my project even after refreshing the project?

Comment: Can you just create the test folder yourself? It's called `spec`

Comment: @Dbz I made it and again run the bundle install, but it is empty

Comment: Why did you think that would generate a test folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using RoR, if think you need to install `rspec-rails` instead of `rspec`. To create the `test` directory (`spec`, actually) you need to run the [rspec installer: `rails generate rspec:install`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#installation)

With `-T` option your are skipping the `unit-test` framework because you want to use `rspec`, am I right? If this is the case **you don't need a test directory**. `rspec` uses the spec directory instead. As I said, to create the spec folder you need to run the `rspec` installer like this:

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

Comment: Good answer! I always forget this step

Comment: @Leantraxxx What should i do if i want to have the default unit-test framework?
i don't feel ok with Rspec

Comment: Just remove the `-T` option and `rspec` from your `Gemfile`. If your using Rails < 4.0 you will use `unit-test`by default. With Rails >= 4.0 you will use `minitest`. You should follow the guides whatever the case. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/testing.html http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/testing.html